# How to pick loss functions for different datasets for neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, loss-functions, keras

I am very new to this field and currently, I am running different neural nets without knowing which loss function to pick so I am randomly picking them like 'categorical cross entropy' mostly. May someone please provide me some materials to build an understanding of it, I have looked for papers but was not very successful.

Thanks for your help

Comment: ReLU is used as an activation function. Is that what you mean, an activation function?

Comment: sorry, I by mistake wrote relu instead of 'categorical cross entropy' . No, I wanted to know which loss function works better for what type of data and how to understand that

Answer (score 1):

Regarding terminology, you are working with the "objective function" of neural networks, i.e., the equation(s) that reveals how well a network works, as well as how the error is minimized and learning accomplished.  "Loss functions" and cost functions are objective functions.   Don't get tripped up by the comment that mentioned ReLU, since that evokes a highly-specific type of "activation" function in neural networks, which you are not interested in for this question.

For neural networks, cross-entropy error is typically recommended as the loss function (objective function) for classification problems, while mean-square-error (MSE) is recommended for function approximation (predicting a specific outcome value) like regression analysis.

Any neural network book by [Christopher Bishop](https://www.amazon.com/Christopher-M.-Bishop/e/B001IGLMNY%3Fref=dbs_a_mng_rwt_scns_share) will help navigate through the learning.

Comment: thanks, I will start with one of his books then